# How does a Siamese neural network calculate distance between outputs with triplet loss?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, siamese-network

I am using a Siamese neural network to learn similarity between text.

Here is a SNN network I created for this task: it feeds two inputs into a Bidirectional LSTM, which shares/updates weights, and then produces two outputs. The distance between these two outputs is then calculated.

```
    input_1 = Input(shape=(max_len,))
    input_2 = Input(shape=(max_len,))

    lstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)) # Won't work on GPU
    embeddings_initializer = Constant(embed_matrix)
    emb =  Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index)+1,
                     embedding_dim,
                     embeddings_initializer=embeddings_initializer,
                     input_length=max_len,
                     weights=[embed_matrix],
                     trainable=True)

    e1 = emb(input_1)
    x1 = lstm_layer(e1)

    e2 = emb(input_2)
    x2 = lstm_layer(e2)

    mhd = lambda x: exponent_neg_cosine_distance(x[0], x[1]) 
    merged = Lambda(function=mhd, output_shape=lambda x: x[0], name='cosine_distance')([x1, x2])
    preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=preds)

    model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",  metrics=['acc'], optimizer = optimizer)
```

However, I read recently that using triplet loss could improve my SNN. This is an example of a SNN that makes use of triplet loss for similarity learning:

```
embedding_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Bidirectional(LSTM(50, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(emb_size, activation='sigmoid')
])

input_anchor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,))
input_positive = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,))
input_negative = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,))

embedding_anchor = embedding_model(input_anchor)
embedding_positive = embedding_model(input_positive)
embedding_negative = embedding_model(input_negative)

output = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([embedding_anchor, embedding_positive, embedding_negative], axis=1)

net = tf.keras.models.Model([input_anchor, input_positive, input_negative], output)
net.summary()

net.compile(loss=triplet_loss, optimizer=adam_optim)
```

```
def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.4):
    """
    Implementation of the triplet loss function
    Arguments:
    y_true -- true labels, required when you define a loss in Keras, you don't need it in this function.
    y_pred -- python list containing three objects:
            anchor -- the encodings for the anchor data
            positive -- the encodings for the positive data (similar to anchor)
            negative -- the encodings for the negative data (different from anchor)
    Returns:
    loss -- real number, value of the loss
    """
    print('y_pred.shape = ',y_pred)
    
    total_lenght = y_pred.shape.as_list()[-1]
#     print('total_lenght=',  total_lenght)
#     total_lenght =12
    
    anchor = y_pred[:,0:int(total_lenght*1/3)]
    positive = y_pred[:,int(total_lenght*1/3):int(total_lenght*2/3)]
    negative = y_pred[:,int(total_lenght*2/3):int(total_lenght*3/3)]

    # distance between the anchor and the positive
    pos_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor-positive),axis=1)

    # distance between the anchor and the negative
    neg_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor-negative),axis=1)

    # compute loss
    basic_loss = pos_dist-neg_dist+alpha
    loss = K.maximum(basic_loss,0.0)
 
    return loss
```

My confusion lies in the SNN network with the triplet loss. How is the distance between the three outputs calculated?

In the first SNN code chunk I included, this line     `merged = Lambda(function=mhd, output_shape=lambda x: x[0], name='cosine_distance')([x1, x2])` is calculating the distance between the two vectors.

But in the second SNN, I don't see where/if distance between the 3 vectors is calculated. If no distance calculation is necessary, why is that the case?

Comment: the second code is incomplete, it doesn't define loss

Comment: apologies, you are right. it is added now!

Comment: well.. the distance is right there, in the `triplet_loss`. They split previously concatenated vector into three parts, calculate the diff norms (`K.sum(K.square(...)..)`), and apply the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you concatenated the three embedding vectors in the output. I suggest you peruse the document at https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_network/.

There, you'll find the below code snippet:

```
class DistanceLayer(layers.Layer):
    """
    This layer is responsible for computing the distance between the anchor
    embedding and the positive embedding, and the anchor embedding and the
    negative embedding.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, anchor, positive, negative):
        ap_distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor - positive), -1)
        an_distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor - negative), -1)
        return (ap_distance, an_distance)


anchor_input = layers.Input(name="anchor", shape=target_shape + (3,))
positive_input = layers.Input(name="positive", shape=target_shape + (3,))
negative_input = layers.Input(name="negative", shape=target_shape + (3,))

distances = DistanceLayer()(
    embedding(resnet.preprocess_input(anchor_input)),
    embedding(resnet.preprocess_input(positive_input)),
    embedding(resnet.preprocess_input(negative_input)),
)

siamese_network = Model(
    inputs=[anchor_input, positive_input, negative_input], outputs=distances
)
```

As you can see, they send the embeddings to the `DistanceLayer` class in which positive and negative distances are computed, and then returned as a tuple which is to be placed in the output of the model.